# Set fixed the deployment address of a web service in WCF

Tags: silverlight, wcf, web-services

I have a simple WCF service project and a Silverlight project that queries the database through this service. 
Is it possible to set the address (actually only the port number since I deploy on localhost) of the service, fixed? 
Because everytime I rebuild the web service, it changes the address and I need to update also the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file from Silverlight in order to update the reference.

Answer (score 0):

You want to configure an ASP.NET project to consistently run on the same port within Visual Studio Development Server?

- Right click on your ASP.NET project and select `Properties`
- Choose the `Web` tab in the properties window (should be the third option)
- Under the `Servers` section (the second section), you'll have a radio button check for `Use Visual Studio Development Server`, and then by default a subselection labelled `Auto-assign Port`. Simply change this subselection to `Specific port`, and then choose a port number.

Now your project will always run under the specified port on the Development Server, e.g. `http://localhost:12345/MyService.svc` and `http://localhost:12345/Default.aspx`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I dont want to set the address from the client. The problem is that I want to set the web service on a fixed port like http://localhost:FIXEDPORT/MyService.svc, and I want to set the FIXEDPORT fixed , because everytime it pics a random new port. I believe this is some ASP.NET web developer server port related thingy.